# How to loop through cells and concatenate with comma-delimited separators?

Tags: vba, excel

I created the script below to loop through all yellow cells on a sheet and, when done, copy/paste the final concatenated result of everything, to a report showing all values of cells colored yellow.

Essentially, the script produces something like this.

```
Task#6 Map Central Email Change to: Owner Group 
Task#6 Map Central Email Change to: Owner Role
Task#6 Map Central Email Change to: Task Description
Task#7 Map Tri Email Change to: Owner Group 
Task#7 Map Tri Email Change to: Owner Role
Task#7 Map Tri Email Change to: Task Description 
If the whole row is yellow, I simply get this:
Task#14ADDED!!
Task#15ADDED!!
```

Just today my colleagues said they want to see the results like this:

```
Task#6 Map Central Email Change to: Owner Group; Owner Role; Task Description
Task#7 Map Tri Email Change to: Owner Group; Owner Role; Task Description
Task#14ADDED!!
```

How can I modify the code to print results like I described in the example directly above, where, for, each Task#, the results are separated by a semi-colon?  I designed this code a while back, and I’ve been looking at it in this format for a while, now I can’t seem to get my mind around the new format.

```
Sub UpdateFormat()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Version Control")
LRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").Select
    Set R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count
    Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").Select
        For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                Set Value = Cells(i, j)
                TaskNo = Cells(i, 2)
                TaskTitle = Cells(i, 3)

                Title = Cells(1, j)
                    If Cells(i, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                        finalset = finalset & vbCrLf & "Task#" & TaskNo & "ADDED!!"
                        GoTo here:

                        Else
                        finalset = finalset & vbCrLf & "Task#" & TaskNo & " " & TaskTitle & " " & "Change to: " & Title
                    End If
            End If
        Next
here:
    Next

    Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value & finalset & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Comment: You should provide sample data screenshot including row and column header as this helps visualize what needs to be done. Do you need to reset the cell color at the end of each Version Control update?

Comment: Will all of your source data be on three related rows as above? And if any part yellow, do you keep all three rows? If so, you can (a) Dim a new string variable,; (2) When you find color, then build string using offset to get to 2nd & 3rd row of task. I would change your code so you increment rows by 3 rather than 1 since that constitutes a related task.

Comment: Better yet, you should use "Scripting.Dictionary" object (Key as the TaskNo & TaskTitle, Value as the Title), this allows you to track what has been added/changed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid a Dictionary, you can just use an extra variable to keep track of which titles need to be written, and then just create the output record when you finish processing the row:

```
Sub UpdateFormat()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Dim TaskNo
    Dim TaskTitle
    Dim Title
    Dim finalset As String
    Dim partset As String

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Version Control")
    LRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").UsedRange
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            TaskNo = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            TaskTitle = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            If .Cells(i, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                finalset = finalset & vbCrLf & "Task#" & TaskNo & "ADDED!!"
            Else
                'Use a temporary variable to concatenate all the relevant titles
                partset = ""
                For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    If .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                        'Set Value = Cells(i, j)
                        Title = .Cells(1, j)
                        partset = partset & Title & "; "
                    End If
                Next
                'See if the temporary variable contains anything
                If partset <> "" Then
                    'If it does, append it to the end of "finalset"
                    '(remove the last two characters from "partset" as that will be a trailing "; ")
                    finalset = finalset & vbCrLf & "Task#" & TaskNo & " " & TaskTitle & " " & "Change to: " & Left(partset, Len(partset) - 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value & finalset & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Comment: @ryguy72 - In response to your comment to Ibo (thanking me?), you are getting multiple CR/LFs because you are placing one at the start of the calculated string, and also adding one at the end of the calculated string.  So when you run the macro twice, without adding anything new into column A, the CR/LF at the start of the new string will immediately follow the CR/LF at the end of the old string.  So that raises the question ... what is the rationale for constantly appending the data to the cell in column D one row below the last used cell in column A, rather than using a new cell each time?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Patrick, you should use dictionaries and for that you need to add Scripting Runtime (in VBE Tools/Referenmces/check Microsoft Runtime Scripting).

This code should do the job. I could not test it because I don't have a sample data so try it and see if it throws an error or not. You can get from there.

You don't need to select worksheets to define a range. It will slow down the performance if you are dealing with many lines like that apart from it will be flickering, let alone that there is no need to select the sheet unless you really want to watch the sheet while it is being populted

here is the code:

```
Sub UpdateFormat()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim TaskNo As String
    Dim TaskTitle As String
    Dim Titke As String
    Dim dict As Dictionary

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Version Control")
    LRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").Select

    Set R = Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").UsedRange
    For i = 1 To R.Rows.Count

    'Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate").Select

    Set dict = New Dictionary

    With Worksheets("PaperlessTemplate")
        For j = 1 To R.Columns.Count
            If .Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                Set Value = .Cells(i, j)
                TaskNo = .Cells(i, 2)
                TaskTitle = .Cells(i, 3)
                Title = .Cells(1, j)

                If .Cells(i, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                    finalset = finalset & vbCrLf & "Task#" & TaskNo & "ADDED!!"
                    GoTo here:

                    Else
                        If dict.Exists(TaskNo) Then 'edit the item of dictionary with the new Title
                            finalset = dict(TaskNo)
                            dict(TaskNo) = finalset & "; " & Title
                        Else 'add to the dictionary
                            dict.Add TaskNo, "Task#" & TaskNo & " " & TaskTitle & " Change to: " & Title
                        End If

                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

here:
            Next

```
        Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value = Worksheets("Version Control").Cells(LRow, 4).Value & finalset & vbCrLf

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks YowE3K!!  This does almost exactly what I want.  I can definitely live with it!  All I'd ask is whether or not there is any way to get rid of the extra vbCrLf, which seems to popup once in a while.  I re-wrote my code, and came up with something similar to what you gave me.  I, too, have some superfluous vbCrLf characters in my results.  Is there an easy way to go through the contents of the final cell where everything is written, just before the end of the script, and delete every line that has ONLY vbCrLf in it?  Thanks everyone!!